# Fullscreen with fade transition in Electron app

Tags: macos, electron

I'm wondering if it is possible to open a new window in fullscreen mode but with a fade-type transition (not a sliding transition) in the same way as when starting a presentation on Keynote.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nfFK.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Taht is not an `electron` feature but you might be able to accomplish it through your `BrowserWindow` events and then handle the fade-in through your content.

The gist: listen for a full-screen event in your main context. When received, send a message to the render context to blacken screen and do a fade-up.

> **Event: 'enter-full-screen'**
>   Emitted when the window enters a full-screen state.
>
> **Event: 'leave-full-screen'**
>   Emitted when the window leaves a full-screen state.
>
> **Event: 'enter-html-full-screen'**
>   Emitted when the window enters a full-screen state triggered by HTML API.
>
> **Event: 'leave-html-full-screen'**
>   Emitted when the window leaves a full-screen state triggered by HTML API.